# Multiple VLANs with same subnet behind single ASA

Tags: routing, cisco-asa, vlan, subnet, testing

Suppose you have three groups of servers on the following VLANs and subnets:

```
Name         VLAN ID    Subnet
-----------------------------------
Production      3       10.0.0.0/24
Test           103      10.0.0.0/24
Lab            111      10.0.0.0/24
```

Suppose also that `Production` is connected to the internet with a Cisco ASA as its gateway at `10.0.0.1`.

The purpose of `Test` and `Lab` is to allow us to replicate as closely as possible the servers on the `Production` network so that we can safely test changes to them without impacting production.

If you naively replicate the servers on the `Production` network and connect them to `Test` then they retain their `10.0.0.0/24` IP addresses as shown in the above table.  Now suppose I want to also provide a connection to the internet for the `Test` network through the same Cisco ASA.  It seems like this would be a problem because the ASA would base its routing decisions on IP addresses of which there are now duplicates on different VLANs.

This leaves me with the following questions:

1. Is there a way to provide internet access to multiple VLANs which incidentally have the same subnet behind a single ASA?
2. If so, how is this acheived?  How would the ASA know to which VLAN to send a given packet if both VLANs have the same subnet?
3. Is there a better way to provide internet connectivity to a test network containing servers with the same IP addresses as production?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the ASA and license you have, you could use [contexts](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa90/configuration/guide/asa_90_cli_config/ha_contexts.html#pgfId-1035807) which create virtual ASAs within the ASA. Each is independent of the other. This would also allow you to test ASA configs before putting them on production. Each vlan interface is assigned to a context. Packets coming in are [classified](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa90/configuration/guide/asa_90_cli_config/ha_contexts.html#pgfId-1124172) (in your situation, via MAC of the vlan interface) and then sent to their respective context.

Another option would be to have 3 routers, one per vlan, performing NAT to a central subnet that the ASA is on.